# tikzmark no shape named a21 known

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikzmark

I am not able to compile the following. I get an error `no shape named a21 is known`. What is the mistake I am making?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\begin{document}
aaammmm\tikzmark{a21} kkkkkkkkkk PPPPPPPPPPPPPPP\tikzmark{a22}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[->] (a21) to[bend right] (a22);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does `(pic cs: a21)` work?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel, I confirm that it does, at least on my TL2022.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel is correct: since `\tikzmark` doesn't create a node (the very first version did, but now `\tikzmarknode` is used for that) then you need to use a different way to refer to its coordinates and that's what the `(pic cs: ...)` syntax is for.

Answer (score 8):

The correct syntax for referring to a tikzmark is `(pic cs: <tikzmark name>)`. The syntax `(<name>)` refers to a *node*. Early in the development of tikzmark, I separated the *remembering* part from the *node* part of the original `\tikzmark` command so that the location that a tikzmark refers to can be used earlier in the document than the mark itself.  Nodes, on the other hand, have to be used after they are defined (although an even later version of tikzmark introduced the `save node` key to enable entire nodes to be referred to before they are defined).

So the correct version of your code is, as Qrrbrbirlbel says in the comments:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\begin{document}
aaammmm\tikzmark{a21} kkkkkkkkkk PPPPPPPPPPPPPPP\tikzmark{a22}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[->] (pic cs: a21) to[bend right] (pic cs: a22);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

For more on the development of tikzmark, see the package documentation. That also links back to many important questions on this site (important in the sense of guiding the development of tikzmark). It's also worth noting that since tikzmark changed in behaviour a few times since its inception, the syntax of using it also changed from time to time so it is worth checking the documentation particularly when looking at old questions/answers on this site that might have been based on an older version of the package.